# uibinder gwt method call

Tags: gwt, methods, widget, call, uibinder

I'm trying to get used to GWT and UiBinder at the moment. But I can't solve this problem.
An example to show you what I mean:

MainMenu.ui.xml

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:gwt="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui" xmlns:my="urn:import:com.wn.webapp.client.UiBinder">

   <gwt:VerticalPanel>
     <my:TopMenu/>
     <gwt:VerticalPanel>
         <gwt:HTMLPanel>
             <gwt:TextBox/>
         </gwt:HTMLPanel>
         <my:ItemList/>
         <my:PageMenu/>
     </gwt:VerticalPanel>
   </gwt:VerticalPanel>
</ui:UiBinder
```

I created a MainMenu and embedded some ui.xml files into it. This works fine. The website looks good.

But how can I do this?
This is the code for my PageMenu.ui.xml file, which I embedded into MainMenu.ui.xml .

```
public class PageMenu extends Composite{

  private static PageMenuUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(PageMenuUiBinder.class);

  interface PageMenuUiBinder extends UiBinderWidget, PageMenu{}

  public PageMenu(){
      initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }

  public void setButtonText(ArrayListString textIds){
       //doessomething
  }
}
```

Now I want to call for ex. the setButtonText() method in onModuleLoad().

```
public void onModuleLoad()
{
    MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu();
    RootPanel.get().add(this.mainmenu);
    // call it here (setButtonText())
}
```

How can I do this?

Greetings
Laura (I'm not such an experienced programmer yet. So pls be aware of that, when you try to answer :D) THX

Comment: Post the PageMenu.ui.xml too, please.

Comment: It's just an easy example. Not my code itself, cause I mustn't post the code of the company.^^ could look like... <gwt:HTMLPanel> <gwt:Button/> </gwt:HTMLPanel>

Comment: But it's not about content. It's just about calling the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to the `button.setText()` you must have access to the `button` first. So, your `PageMenu.ui.xml` must have something like:

```
<gwt:Button ui:field="button" />
```

and your PageMenu.java must have the field declaration:

```
@UiField
Button button;
```

Implement the getters for the PageMenu (at MainMenu) and for the button (at PageMenu), then you can do:

```
public void onModuleLoad()
{
    MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu();
    RootPanel.get().add(this.mainmenu);
    mainmenu.getPageMenu().getButton().setText("What you want.");
}
```

Comment: Yes I know how to work with uifields^^ in the PageMenu.java class itself, but I need to have access to that button from another class. (onModuleLoad() is not declared in PageMenu.class) So. Normally I would create an instance of PageMenu und use the method. But PageMenu is embedded in MainMenu und MainMenu is created in onModuleLoad(). So... I think I need to get access to the PageMenu instance, which is created by MainMenu somehow. But how?^^

Comment: So it's so much simple. Just implement a getPageMenu in MainMenu class, a getButton in the PageMenu class and do: mainmenu.getPageMenu().getButton().setText()

Comment: Wow thank you very much. Dunno why I didn't figure it out myself. So simple. =)

Comment: I changed the answer according to our understanding. Please mark as accepted if you have met your needs.

Comment: can't cause I don't have enough reputations^^

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 2 accessors :

- getButton() in PageMenu.java
- getPageMenu() in MainMenu.java

You now can call it with

```
mainMenu.getPageMenu().getButton().setText("your text");
```

Comment: Thanks. =) But I think first something like this is needed in MainMenu.java. PageMenu pageMenu; @UiFactory
    PageMenu makePageMenu()
    {
        this.pageMenu = new pageMenu();
        return this.control;
    } Or is there an other way to get the instance?

Comment: You have several ways to get the instance of a Ui Object. That depends on what you need. If you have to construct your object with one or more parameters, you could use these annotations: `@UiConstructor`, `@UiFactory` or `@UiField(provided=true)` as described here : [link](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder?hl=fr#Using_a_widget). If you don't need a constructor with parameter, you should use `@UiField` annotation without parameter provided or `provided=false`.